# Problem accessing orion-psb-image-R5.4 on FIWARE Lab using ssh

Tags: fiware-orion

these are the steps i did :
1- created a keypair.
2- downloaded the keypair and used puttygen to generate a private key
3-created a new instance using the orion-psb-image-R5.4 image for a context broker.
4-created a security group and added a rule that opened the ssh port
5- associated a floating ip to that image
6-tried to access the image from putty using the floating ip and the private key generated in step 2

putty  gives me this error:

```
Disconnected : No supported authentication methods available (server sent:publickey).
```

I would like to know how to solve this issue and understand the reason for it.

update:
Screen shots:
[1.loading the downloaded keypair into puttygen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDsCz.jpg)
[2.the downloaded keypair file from fiware lab (keypair.pem) and the generated private key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XWbe.png)
[3.entering the floating ip for the contextbroker instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0U8U.png)
[4.loading the generated private key to use during connection establishment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKYIT.png)
[5.the error message when i try to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu0oO.jpg)

Comment: In which FIWARE Lab regison are you deploying your instance?

Comment: crete lab region

Comment: Could you update your question to provide screenshots of steps 2 and 6, pls?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with key generation or Putty configuration. Unfortunatelly, the question post doesn't include enough detail to provide a more precices anser.

I'd suggest you to edit your question post to include full detail of each step you have done (even including screenshots as you go).

**EDIT**: use `centos` as user login instead of `root`

Comment: it worked thanks alot! , can u tell me how to know the login name of any instance i deploy and can u please direct me to a tutorial on how to use fiwarelab api's for my own application ex: sending post requests to this instance using a mobile application

Comment: I understand that each image template could use a different login but probably all the ones based in CenOS (as orion-psb-image-Rx.y is) use "centos". With regards to tutorial, I'll suggest to have a look to the introduction to Orion Context Broker at: https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/orion-context-broker-20180928, then try to follow the walkthrough published here: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html. Enjoy it! :)